# How to uniquely identify a user, before updating just their info in the database - asp.net/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm just looking for "best practice" reassurance on working with jQuery and ASP.Net, before working on my new project.  I'll take a simple example.

1. A user logs on to my website, using forms authentication
2. Their userID is stored in the Session("userID") variable
3. When logged in, their screen shows a list of cars available
4. The user wants to re-order them into preference order, which is then posted back to an aspx web page from jQuery

What is the best way of uniquely identifiying the user, so that only their preference order is updated?

Should I use the Session("userID") on the server side, to ensure it's only that users data that is updated?

Or when creating the page, should I "send" the unique userID to the browser, and store in a label on the screen, and then post that back to the aspx webpage, when the update is made?  Or is that a huge security hole - in so much as if I post a uniqueID to the browser, the user could change it before posting the data back by jQuery, thereby updating another users information?

Thanks for any guidance,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use integrated security?

```
User.Identity.Name
```

You can set up users and passwords (authentication), create roles (groups of users), and create permissions (rules for controlling access to parts of your application). - Sir Microsoft

Because Sessions Timeout, i think that would be a great choice.  Why leave a person logged on forever?

Comment: Hi - as the page being posted to, would most likely be a web service, is user.identity.name available to a web service?  Or if I just post back to a normal aspx page, is it freely available to that?

Comment: Ah, interesting, I'm really not sure, but i would imagine that the webservice would allow authentication.  You would just have to manually pass the Identity to it.  Or at least one unique property of that Identity.

Answer (score 1):

If you send it to the client, it can be manipulated. If you receive it from the client, it can be falsified. in short: never trust the client about anything.

If you store the user in a hidden element or a JS variable, what prevents a savvy user like anyone on this site from altering that data with the developer console before submitting it back?

Comment: You can always encrypt the client side and let your server take a breathe of fresh air.

Comment: I agree. @Mark Tait basically answered his own question. Just ask yourself why open yourself up to things like that in the first place, if there is an alternative that is more secure.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the responses so far.  So my user logs in, and has the unique idenitifier of "7" - would you just use the DESEncrypt (within ASP.Net) and send the encrypted value to the client, and send that back with the jQuery data - or would you recommend continuing to use Session state on the server side?  Thanks again.